# Searching nearby LifX Bulbs in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, lifx

I am working on a project to integrate light bulb controls using LifX. I tested out on the official Lifx app, it can scan on nearby lightbulbs that hasn't been added on its signed on account before. I would like to do the same. The most promising library I came across (besides tons of others that I tried) is [LibxNet](https://github.com/dotMorten/LifxNet), its fairly easy to use and is somewhat the most popular one.

```
    client = await LifxNet.LifxClient.CreateAsync();
    client.DeviceDiscovered += Client_DeviceDiscovered;
    client.DeviceLost += Client_DeviceLost;
    client.StartDeviceDiscovery();

...

    private async void Client_DeviceDiscovered(object sender, LifxNet.LifxClient.DeviceDiscoveryEventArgs e)
    {
        var bulb = e.Device as LifxNet.LightBulb;
        await client.SetDevicePowerStateAsync(bulb, true); //Turn bulb on
        await client.SetColorAsync(bulb, Colors.Red, 2700); //Set color to Red and 2700K Temperature            
    }
```

Unfortunately, best of my integration, I cannot get it to work for Xamarin Forms using the implementation of this nuget library.

I already added necessary permissions which is the same as the official LifX app.

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

The official [documentation](https://lan.developer.lifx.com/) doesn't really give much as it only says UDP stuffs which I am not even familiar with. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *" I cannot get it to work for Xamarin Forms"*? What is the observed behavior and how does it deviate from the expected behavior?

Comment: It just could not detect my nearby Lifx bulb which can be detected by the official app.